# Trigger Steamdeck OSK without sdk

Tags: steam, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a easy way to trigger the Steamdeck OSK in Desktop-Mode (for example via bash, dbus,...) without using the Steam SDK on Linux?

Like calling some .so-function or Trigger some virtual keypress for Steam+x

I expecting a hint or a possibilty to trigger the OSK via programming